# Как найти все значения, соответствующие ключам из набора, если ключи могут повторяться?

Tags: mysql

Есть такая табличка `Data`.

```
| id | Key | Value  |
|----|-----|--------|
| 1  | 0   | f30467 |
| 2  | 1   | 406b67 |
| 3  | 2   | c029bd |
| 4  | 3   | 5c512f |
| 5  | 4   | 739fd6 |
| 6  | 5   | 096b71 |
| 7  | 6   | b1e8b2 |
| 8  | 7   | e71828 |
| 9  | 8   | 8d8566 |
| 10 | 9   | 94dcdc |
```

Вот образец необходимой выборки:

```
| Key | Value  |
|-----|--------|
| 0   | f30467 |
| 1   | 406b67 |
| 2   | c029bd |
| 2   | c029bd |
| 0   | f30467 |
```

Я пробовал использовать такой запрос:

```
SELECT `Key`, `Value` FROM `Data` WHERE `Key` IN ('0', '1', '2', '2', '0')
```

Он не дает нужного результата:

```
| Key | Value  |
|-----|--------|
| 0   | f30467 |
| 1   | 406b67 |
| 2   | c029bd |
```

Ссылка на пример в [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bdbd/4).

---

Следующий запрос дает нужный результат, однако это не самое оптимальное решение для большого набора значений `Key`:

```
SELECT `Key`, `Value` FROM `Data` WHERE `Key` = '0'
UNION ALL
SELECT `Key`, `Value` FROM `Data` WHERE `Key` = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT `Key`, `Value` FROM `Data` WHERE `Key` = '2'
UNION ALL
SELECT `Key`, `Value` FROM `Data` WHERE `Key` = '2'
UNION ALL
SELECT `Key`, `Value` FROM `Data` WHERE `Key` = '0'
```

Ссылка на пример в [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6bdbd/4).

Как получить необходимый мне результат без использования конструкции `UNION ALL`?

Comment: а в чем смысл получать несколько раз одну и туже запись? получите уникальные и в ЯП расставляйте их как угодно

Comment: @splash58, это сейчас и сделано на ЯП, однако я хотел бы переложить эту задачу на плечи базы данных, если возможно обойтись без нескольких запросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql` не предоставляет необходимых операторов, ни `unnest`, ни `values` в блоке `from`, знакомых по `postgresql` и ничего другого взамен. Даже появившийся в 5.7 JSON нельзя распаковать в набор строк. Поэтому единственное, что можно попробовать сделать с вашим вариантом запроса - это переписать в `join`:

```
select `Key`, `Value`
    from `Data`
        join (
            select 0 as `Key`
            union all
            select 1
            union all
            select 2
            union all
            select 2
            union all
            select 0
        ) targetkeys using(`Key`)
```

Но сомневаюсь, что это будет выгоднее вашего варианта запроса. И, вроде бы, не гарантирует порядок следования.

Comment: Жаль, конечно. Придется оставить обработку данных так, как есть (в ЯП).